# Issue to pass argument to the function on button click in custom module

Tags: forms

I have created a custom module in which list of mp3 tracks being displayed. After every track there is remove button and button id is actually nid of the track.

Now what I want is when I click on remove button particular button id (Which is nid actually) should be passed to the function remove_track.

Since I am new to the module development help me to know how to pass the argument to the function. Here is my code and screenshot hope it will help you.

```
function my_form($form, &$form_state) 
{ 
 $tr = playlist_edit_gettracks(arg(1));
    $node = array();
    $pl_name=array();
    $pl_name=getplaylist_to_edit(arg(1));
    $tr = playlist_edit_gettracks(arg(1));
    $pl_name11=$pl_name[1];
    //array('page callback' => 'my_page');

$node['text'] = array(
    '#label' => 'selected',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#id'=>'edit-playlist-name',
    '#value' => $pl_name[1],
);


for($i=0; $i<sizeof($tr); $i++){
    $node['tracks'.$i] = array(  
       '#prefix' => '<div class = "remove-track">', 
       '#markup' =>'<br><a>'.$tr[$i]->title.'</a>',           
    );

   *$node['remove'.$i] = array(
       '#id' => $tr[$i]->nid,
       '#type' => 'submit',
       '#value' => 'Remove', 
       '#submit' => array('remove_track'),   //HERE I WANT TO CALL THE FUNCTION AND PASS THE ARGUMENT  
       '#suffix' => '</div>',                              
    );
}
$form['#submit'] = 'my_form_submit';
  //drupal_form_submit('playlist_edit_gettracks');
    $node['submit'] = array(
         '#type' => 'submit',
         '#value' => 'Update', 
         //'page callback' => 'my_page',   
         '#submit' => array('my_form_submit'),
    );
  return $node;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Where is the `remove_track` function? Is the `remove_track` function php or javascript? Do you want this to work via ajax?

Comment: remove_track is php function in the same file. Can I call javascript function? I mean can I implement the remove operation using ajax?

Comment: yes you could do this with ajax via the drupal form api

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined error while trying to execute jquery. jquey is not executing all over the site. I have enabled jquery_update module.

Comment: Hod do you expect me to help you with that? Check console for the line/fie of the javascript error.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery on a Drupal site, you have to do it the right way. Check out this page, particularly the "Javascript closures" section. https://www.drupal.org/node/171213